# Need Help With Calc Homework Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $x^*$ means $5x^2 - x$. Then what does $(y+3)^*$ mean?

Comment: Are there parenthesis missing? Is that really $5\times 2$? If so, why not write $10$ instead?

Comment: @hardmath: Avoid editing the question until the OP has clarified the intended meaning.

Comment: 5x^2 is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x^* = 5 x^2 - x$ then

$$(y+3)^* = 5(y+3)^2 - (y+3 )= 5(y^2 + 6 y + 9) - y - 3 = 5 y^2 + 29 y + 42  $$

Comment: There's a sign error in the last expression (the x coefficient is net positive), but one character edits are not allowed! I leave it to your discretion.

Comment: So, +42 is correct?

Comment: Yes. You can quickly check if this is correct by substituting $y$ to a particular value and look at what you get on the left-hand side and on the right-hand side. Try $y=-3$ you get $0$ on left and $5\times 9-29\times 3+42 = 0$ on right ;)

Answer (score 4):

By 5x2 do you mean $5x^2$? In such a case, simply replace every instance of $x$ with $(y+3)$, and then expand.

For example, $f(x) = 2x+2 \Longrightarrow f(y+3) = 2(y+3)+2 = 2y+6+2 = 2y+8$.